# vagrant ubuntu virtual box fails to configure network

Tags: networking, connection, vagrant, virtualbox

I have the following setup:

Host machine: Windows 7

Guest:

Oracle Virtual Box: version 5.0

Vagrant: version 1.8.5

Guest Additions: version 4.2.0

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # A standard Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit box
  # For more boxes, you can look at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant_provision.sh"
  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
end
```

vagrant_provision.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo apt-get update
echo "Installing Apache.."
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
echo "Installing Tomcat.."
sudo apt-get install -y tomcat7
echo "Installing Tomcat7 docs.."
sudo apt-get install -y tomcat7-docs
echo "Installing Tomcat7 administration webapps.."
sudo apt-get install -y tomcat7-admin
echo "Installing Tomcat7 examples webapps.."
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-examples
echo "Installing Git.."
sudo apt-get install -y git
echo "Installing Maven.."
sudo apt-get install -y maven
echo "Installing Java 7.."
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
echo "Setting environment variables for Java 7.."
sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java7-set-default
```

when running vagrant up, I get this error/message at the end of the script execution:

Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'configure_networks' on the detect guest OS 'linux', but the guest doesn't support that capability. This capability is required for your configuration of Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to avoid this capability or fix the issue by creating the capability.

There seems to be no straight-forward solution to this. Has anyone come across the problem and solved it or is there a different combination of versions that is actually working?

Thanks
AHL

Comment: It has worked for me: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6426#issuecomment-234977448

Comment: do you have to use this box "config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32". I had a similar issue and I changed to "ubuntu/trusty" (check the exact name) and it worked!